# Onedrive parameter to control zoom in embedded document

Tags: iframe, onedrive

Hi I've a url like this:

> https://onedrive.live.com/embed?resid=xxxxxxxxx&authkey=xxxxxxxx&em=2

to embed a onedrive document, it works fine but I wanted to know if there is any parameter to control the zoom of the loaded document.
Thanks